# How to modify a django model attributes in js

Tags: django

I have insert js in the changelist form

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('Name','Creator','owners','Topic')
    search_fields = ['Name']
    class Media:
        js = ['/site_media/js/taskList.js',]
```

then i want to set the attribute `"search_fields"` in the taskList.js, i have no idear how to implement this, this is the current code of taskList.js

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {


        });
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

Comment: You won't be able to set the `search_fields` attribute on the model admin instance via JavaScript without re-instatiating the object (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Also, the call to $(document).ready() is redundant. The $(function(){}) already does that.

Comment: Then how can i set dynamic search_fileds? i would like to add an advanced search feature such as some check box, list box and then sync the value to search_fileds

Comment: My advice would be to set all of the possible fields you want searchable in Python, and then alter the UI via JavaScript.